# Bind Query inside middleware

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm trying to write a "Binder" middleware that will validate any request query using a struct type with gin bindings/validators

So for example, let's say I have an endpoint group called `/api/subject` which requires the query string to have a subject code and an ID that will be validated using the following struct (called `entity.Subject`):

```golang
type Subject struct {
    Code string `binding:"required,alphanum"`
    ID   string `binding:"required,alphanum,len=4"`
}
```

That's just one example, but I'd like to be able to pass any struct type to this middleware, because I'd like to access the query data on future handlers without worrying about query validation.

So I tried something like this:

```golang
func Binder(t reflect.Type) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        obj := reflect.New(t).Elem().Interface()
        if err := c.BindQuery(&obj); err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        c.Set(t.Name(), obj)
    }
}
```

And added this middleware like so:

```golang
apiGroup := router.Group("/api")
{
    // other subgroups/endpoints
    // ...
    subjectGroup := apiGroup.Group("/subject", middleware.Binder(reflect.TypeOf(entity.Subject{})))
}
```

And later on, in another handler function, let's say `GetSubject`, I want to access the subject data passed by doing `c.MustGet("Subject").(entity.Subject)`

But this isn't working =(, when I print `obj`, it's just an empty interface, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do something similar!

I created the following middleware

```golang
var allowedTypes = []binding.Binding{
    binding.Query,
    binding.Form,
    binding.FormPost,
    binding.FormMultipart,
}

func Bind(name string, data interface{}, bindingType binding.Binding) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ok := false
        for _, b := range allowedTypes {
            if b == bindingType {
                ok = true
            }
        }
        if !ok {
            ctx.AbortWithError(
                http.StatusInternalServerError,
                fmt.Errorf("Bind function only allows %v\n", allowedTypes),
            )
        }
        _ = ctx.MustBindWith(data, bindingType)
        ctx.Set(name, data)
    }
}
```

Remember to pass a pointer to your desired type in the call, like so:

`router.GET("/something", Bind("Object", &myObject, binding.Query))`

I restricted only to a few binding types because they allow `ShouldBind` to be called multiple times, whereas `JSON`, `XML` and others consume the `Request` body.

This way you can pass multiple Bind middlewares and if the validation fails it automatically aborts with `http.StatusBadRequest`